# RequireJS multiple module in single file

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I want to merge multiple modules into a single file, but I can't find an official document about how to do it. Now I'm using the below method, it works, but I'm wondering about the following:

- Is it technically correct?
- How does RequireJS check whether a module is loaded or not? By using the module name or the file name?
- Will this solution init modules multiple times in some situation?

**index.html**

```
<script src="require.js"></script>
<script>
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'a': 'test',
        'b': 'test'
    }
});

require(['a', 'b'], function () {
    console.log('a & b loaded');
});
</script>
```

**test.js**

```
console.log('loading test.js');
// I have some init here, like "Avoid `console` errors in IE"

define('a', function () {
    console.log('a module');
});

define('b', function () {
    console.log('b module');
});
```

Answer (score 14):

Shangan is right. In http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#define there is a part that says:

*There should only be one module definition per file on disk.*

But if you want to do it anyway I found something like that: It is from official documentation: 
http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-bundles

It says that you can define in which file you can find which modules by `bundles` property. For example: I have file called 
**modules.js** with such content:

```
define('module_one', function(){
    return 'Hello. I am module one';
})

define('module_two', function(){
    return 'Hello. I am module two';
})
```

Then in my **main.js** file I do something like this:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl : 'modules/',
    bundles: {
        'modules': ['module_one', 'module_two']
    }
})

require(['module_one', 'module_two'], function(moduleOne, moduleTwo){
    alert(moduleOne);
    alert(moduleTwo);
})
```

And it works like I want to.

Comment: Since you already defined a bundle "modules", can you directly require that bundle?  Like `require(['bundle1']);` ?

Comment: You mean something like:
`require(['modules'])` ? It won't work, because _modules_ is file name, and `['module_one']` is a module name in this file. That's how I understand that, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Good answer. But `alert`? really?! ;)

Answer (score 12):

This is old but I just bumped into it.
Sure you can have multiple define in the same file, and yes, it makes sense.

The only thing you need to do is to use named defines.

```
define('module1', ['dependency1', 'dependency2'], function (d1, d2) {
    // your code here
}
```

Think that sometimes you don't need your resources to be loaded dynamically, having them loaded all at the beginning might actually be required, co creating a single concatenated/minified js file at packaging time is the best solution.

So you won't take advantage of the "lazy loading" but you still design your app in a modular way by using RequireJS.

Comment: But how to get this file loaded?

Answer (score 0):

**is that correct ?**

NO. There should only be one module definition per file on disk.

**how do RequireJS check a module loaded or not ? using the module name or file name ?**

Using the file name.

**will that init multiple times in some situation ?**

The modules can be grouped into optimized bundles by the optimization tool.

http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html

Example of Hello World module is given here.

http://mydons.com/requirejs-hello-world/

Comment: Thanks, but I using PHP template, that has some nesting JS call, so optimizing look like difficult to me, anyway, I vote up

Comment: Only having one module def per file is recommended practice but that doesn't make having 2 or more always wrong. The "NO" on this answer seems too prescriptive to me. I think AlexCode is on the money.

Like most stuff, the key is to understand why the 1 per module is advised - I believe it is to allow effective use of r.js, the optimiser.

We have reasons for not using r.js as we have our own optimisation strategy. Loading multiple modules per file (in our case, built one the fly server-side and then delivered from one Ajax request) is part of our custom optimisation.

Its "buyer beware".

Comment: Yeah sure, I'm going to have like milion files each containing 10lines of derived module. I thought RequireJS promised effectivity...