# How do you organize js files so that you can require from them within one npm package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have a couple of nodejs files I want to group together in one folder, because they fit together logically.

Say they're called a.js, b.js, c.js

In my app, I have code that imports from these files like:

`require('a')
 require('b')
 require('c').`

How do I package those files together so that I don't have to change my individual `require`s? Is there an option in package.json file so that I can make those files exportable on a global scale without relying on the directory that contains those files?

Comment: This might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308086/requirejs-multiple-module-in-single-file

Answer (score 0):

You could always create a project (package.json) and include the js files and then manually move it to your corresponding's OS NPM global modules path. For windows this is %AppData%\Roaming\npm\node_modules. After than you can confirm using npm list -g that your package is globally installed

Answer (score 0):

You could create packages a, b, c separately. Like this:

```
|Custom checks' packages
|- package a
|-- package.json
|-- index.js // with the code of your a.js
|- package b
|-- package.json
|-- index.js // with the code of your b.js
|-package c
|-- package.json
|-- index.js // with the code of your c.js
```

On each package.json, you define its entry file by setting the *main* property, so it could be:

```
{
  "name": "a",
  ... some properties
  "main" : "index.js",
  ... some other properties
}
```

Then within each package folder, you run in your console:

```
npm install .
```

Finally in any local project, you can do

```
require('a')
require('b')
require('c')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5270632/cnexans - I am very intrigued by your answer and would like to try this out in my project... where do you place the stuff you mention under the 'You could create packages a, b, c separately. Like this' ? I am using Visual Code and nodeJS